# How to activate/deactivate a selection of a clicked element?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have 3 headings `Administration, Market, DTA`.

[image]

The selection color  is on `Administration`,

When, the user clicks on an other heading for example `Market`.
The selection color  is always on `Administration`.

[image]

I would like the color to be activated on a single heading.

**dashboard.component.html**

```
<ul class="nav-links" *ngFor="let menu of menus; let i = index">
    <li [ngClass]="{ selected: selectedTab === menu.route }">
      <a
        routerLink="{{ menu.route }}"
        routerLinkActive="active"
        (click)="toggleMenu(i); selectedTab = menu.route"
      >
        <i class="{{ menu.class }}"></i>
        <span class="links_name"> {{ menu.item }} </span>
        <i
          class="{{ menu.arrowDown }} iconArrow"
          *ngIf="selectedTab !== menu.route || !showSubmenu[i]"
        ></i>
        <i
          class="{{ menu.arrowUp }} iconArrow "
          *ngIf="selectedTab === menu.route && showSubmenu[i]"
        ></i>
      </a>
    </li>

    <ng-container *ngFor="let submenu of menu.submenus; let j = index">
      <li *ngIf="showSubmenu[i]">
        <a routerLink="{{ submenu.route }}">
          <i class="{{ submenu.class }}"></i>
          <span class="links_name"> {{ submenu.item }} </span>
        </a>
      </li>
    </ng-container>
```

I can share you my code [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-jgb6yo?file=src/app/views/dashboard/dashboard.component.html).

The pseudo is `toto` and the password `1234`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Headers' route settings are not routing properly. First of all, remove slash from redirect routes of modules and change them with appropriate route. For example, route setting for the market module route can be as follows:

```
{
     path: '',
     pathMatch: 'full',
     redirectTo: 'indice',
},
```

Second, add also `routerLinkActive="active"` to submenus routes.

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-jgb6yo-54tkfo?file=src/app/views/dashboard/views/dta/dta-routing.module.ts)

Comment: Thanks ! It works, thank you for your help.